# Prevent entering button event more than one time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using simple asp:Button to save a text box content to DB **only once**.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  If(txtMessage.text != string.Empty)
  {
    // Insert into DB Method
    txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
  }
}
```

The problem is when I double click the button, the text box won't be cleared, and the debugger enters the condition, therefore saves the content twice

Any help?

Comment: The best thing to do is disable button using javascript after the first click. If for some reason you can't do that, use a boolean flag like `isClickHandled` and process click event only if it's false.

Answer (score 1):

Save the last button click time and compare it when handling the click

something like:

```
    TimeSpan LastClick = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Subtract(LastClick).TotalMilliseconds < 500)
                return;
        }
        LastClick = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        if(txtMessage.text != string.Empty)
        {
          // Insert into DB Method
              txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Updated forgot a line

Comment: you can change it to 10000 if you want :)